# Get a colormap of different shades to multiple matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am plotting multiple plots generated from a `for` loop. I want each plot to be in a different shade of the same color so that it can be easily identified. I don't know how many plots, because it depends on a user selection (There can be 5 plots or 7 or 8 or etc.).

In this MWE, I used matplotlib `blues` to plot the graphs in different shads of blue. As you can see, the shades are not very different from each other. What parameter do I have to change so that the shades are noticeably different from each other?

(Now, I can "not" use colors at all and let the matplotlib use its default colors by removing `color = blues(xaxis[j])`. But I am looking for shades, not totally different colors.)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
plt.close("all")

blues = cm.get_cmap('Blues', 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

l1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
j=0
xaxis = np.linspace(0.5,1, 1000)
for i in range(0,10):
    l0 = l1*i
    print(l0)
    ax.plot(l1, l0,color = blues(xaxis[j]),label='plot')
    j+=1
    ax.legend()
```

Comment: Instead of `xaxis = np.linspace(0.5,1, 1000)` you should use the real number of colors you need. So `xaxis = np.linspace(0.5,1, 10)`.  If you don't know the exact number beforehand, you could use the maximum expected number instead.  Note that the 5 first values of `np.linspace(0.5,1, 1000)` are `[0.5, 0.5005005, 0.501001, 0.5015015, 0.502002, ... ])` or very close together, while you want values a far apart as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `cm.get_cmap('Blues', 10)` you are creating a colormap of 10 distinct shades of blue. You can access each specific shade like so:

```py
from matplotlib import cm

blues = cm.get_cmap("Blues", 10)
for i in range(blues.N):
    print(f'RGBA {i}:' *(f"{v:.2f}" for v in blues(i)))

# RGBA 0: 0.97 0.98 1.00 1.00
# RGBA 1: 0.88 0.93 0.97 1.00
# RGBA 2: 0.80 0.87 0.94 1.00
# RGBA 3: 0.67 0.81 0.90 1.00
# RGBA 4: 0.51 0.73 0.86 1.00
# RGBA 5: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 6: 0.22 0.53 0.75 1.00
# RGBA 7: 0.11 0.42 0.69 1.00
# RGBA 8: 0.03 0.30 0.59 1.00
# RGBA 9: 0.03 0.19 0.42 1.00
```

The issue here is that the steps of your `xaxis` variable are too small and are converging to the same exact shade of blue due to rounding.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
 
blues = cm.get_cmap("Blues", 10)
xaxis = np.linspace(.5, 1, 1000)
for i in range(10):
    print(f"RGBA {xaxis[i]:.3f}:", *(f"{v:.2f}" for v in blues(xaxis[i])))

# RGBA 0.500: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.501: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.501: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.502: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.502: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.503: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.503: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.504: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.504: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
# RGBA 0.505: 0.35 0.63 0.81 1.00
```

Therefore, your `xaxis` variable should not intermediate the color selection instead, you can simplify your code like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

blues = cm.get_cmap("Blues", 10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

l1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

for i in range(blues.N):
    ax.plot(l1, l1 * i, color=blues(i), label=f"line {i}")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Very descriptive answer! Thank you so much1